# Convert number from text file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, cut

I have a file:

```
 id name date
 1  paul 23.07
 2  john 43.54
 3  marie 23.4
 4  alan  32.54
 5  patrick 32.1
```

I want to print names that start with "p" and have an odd numbered id

My command:
`grep "^p" filename | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | ....`

result:

```
paul
patrick
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow paulc! Is the result you show from  your commands or is that the one you want? What else do you have in your command beyond the `....`? Glad to help, but not sure where you're heading. Personally, I'd recommend doing this in `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk can do it all:

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 && $2 ~ /^p/ && ($1 % 2) == 1 { print $2 }' op.txt
paul
patrick
```

**EDIT**
To use `:` as the field separator:

```
$ awk -F: 'NR > 1 && $2 ~ /^p/ && ($1 % 2) == 1 { print $2 }' op.txt
```

**NR > 1**
Skip the header

**$2 ~ /^p/**
Name field starts with p

**$1 % 2 == 1**
ID field is odd

If all of the above are true:
**{ print $2 }**
Print the name field

Comment: You don't need the `==1` nor the check for it not being the first line as the first line doesn't have a number as the first field.

Comment: but if filed separator is for example ":"?

Comment: You just enclose the code in full blocks like I pointed in my answer below: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} { … }' filename`

Answer (score 0):

How about a little awk?

```
awk '{if ($1 % 2 == 1 && substr($2, 1, 1) == "p") print $2}' filename
```

In awk the fields are split by [spaces, tabs and newlines](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html#Default-Field-Splitting) by default, so your id is available as $1, name as $2 etc. The if is quite self-explanatory, when the condition is true, the name is printed out, otherwise nothing is done. AWK and its syntax is far more friendly than people usually think.

Just remember the basic pattern:

```
BEGIN {
    # ran once in the beginning
}
{
    # done for each line
}
END {
    # ran once in the end
}
```

If you need a more complex parsing, you can keep the script clear and readable in a separate file and call it like this:

```
awk -f script.awk filename
```

Comment: `awk '$1%2&&$2~/^p/{print $2}'`

Comment: Just to clarify, the space FS is implicit, but I will leave it in the answer in case you needed to split the fields by tabs for example. I like other guys' short solutions too. :-)

Comment: It doesn't need splitting on other fields though, you might as well set every environment variable just "in case" if you are putting in a redundant FS.

Comment: True, I also just found out that tabs are implicit too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try this

```
grep -e "[0-9]*[13579]\s\+p[a-z]\+" -o text | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Odd number is easily represented by regex which here we write

```
[0-9]*[13579]
```

If you try to run this command with sample file name `text`

**file: text**

```
 id name date
 1  paul 23.07
 2  john 43.54
 3  marie 23.4
 5  patrick 32.1
38  peter 21.44
10019  peyton 12.02
```

you will get outputs:

```
paul
patrick
peyton
```

Note that `tr -s ' '` uses to make sure that your delimiter is always 1 space.